# Удаление временных файлов при сбое или отмене загузки

Tags: jquery, php, загрузка, файлы

Всем привет! Возник следующий вопрос: Если пользователь грузит файлы через html-форму на сервер (все как положено, т.е. файлы грузятся во временную папку, через ajax показывается список только что загруженных файлов), и вдруг, по неизвестным причинам он закрывает/покидает страницу. Как избавиться от только что загруженных файлов? 
Спасибо, всем кто поможет =)

Comment: Надо ли напрягаться и отслеживать каждую такую загрузку? Может пойти по пути наименьшего сопротивления? Самый простой способ - это написать маленький скрипт, который будет очищать данную папку, повесить на крон, который будет запускать скрипт в определенное время, напр., раз в сутки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Крон.
Удаление файлов, которые, к примеру, старше одного часа